# How to check SOAP output of a C#.NET app?

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, soapui

I'm working on a windows forms C# app in VS2010 (.NET 4.5). The app consumes a web service. The proxy class is, unsurprisingly, inherited from SoapHttpClientProtocol class. The data (records) are set up as a dataset by the xsd that was bundled with the wsdl I used to generate the web reference.

Here's the problem I'm having: one of the web service API calls does not work when I use my app, but calling that same function via SoapUI works just fine. The structure of the call in SoapUI is basically the SOAP envelope with the schema label for the API call wrapping around the values for username and a list node containing the fields in the data record. The error that I get is the super-descriptive "Internal error (from client)".

The API call in the proxy class:

```
    [

System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("http://localhost:8080/updateRecord", RequestNamespace="http://www.<redacted>.com/schemas", ResponseNamespace="http://www.<redacted>.com/schemas", Use=System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped)]
        [return: System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute("issues", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable=true)]
        [return: System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("list", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable=false)]
        public qaIssue[] updateRecord([System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable=true)] string username, [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable=true)] dataRecord record) {
            object[] results = this.Invoke("updateRecord", new object[] {
                        username,
                        record});
            return ((qaIssue[])(results[0]));
        }
```

And this is what the package should look like, at least according to SoapUI:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sch="http://www.<redacted>.com/schemas">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <sch:updateCitation>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <username>LikeI'dLeaveMyUsernameInHere</username>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <record>
          <reportDate>2013-04-15-04:00</reportDate>
          <reportType>Temporary</reportType>
....

         </record>
      </sch:updateRecord>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

There is one other function which attempts to send a data record to the web service as well. Beyond these two functions, though, I don't have any problems whatsoever with any of the other API calls, including those which deliver the records to my app.

Is there any way to leverage either SoapUI or some tool within Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate that I can use to inspect the package that the app is transmitting? Since the call works just fine in SoapUI, surely there's something about my app that's causing this problem...right?

Comment: If you were using "Add Service Reference", then you would be able to use WCF Tracing and message tracing.

Answer (score 0):

RequestBin (http://requestb.in/) is a tool for easily viewing the content of http requests.

Just create a RequestBin and configure your app's endpoint to point to it, then fire a request in from your app and it'll be viewable in your RequestBin.

You could also try using Fiddler (http://fiddler2.com/) if you're interested in capturing request and response messages, but I find RequestBin to be quicker and easier.